# Issues when using hadoop to copy files from grid to local

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distributed-computing, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to copy some files from the hadoop HDFS to local. I used the following command

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal <hdfs path> <local path>
```

The size of the file is just 80M. I had run a job before where I had no issue in copying files of size 70MB to local. However, this time I am having Input/Output error

```
copyToLocal: Input/output error
```

can anyone tell me what could have gone wrong?

Comment: you may want to check the log files for detailed error messages

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the local path folder? Does the folder exist?

Comment: @zhutoulala how to check the logs please? user34790 I have the same problem, how did you resolve it? Does the answer below apply?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a space constraint on your machine. I had the same issue because the file was too big for it to be moved to my local machine. Once I made space, I was able to perform the copyToLocal operation.

Comment: Same exact case as Maria.